# how to identify label from result of speech command model in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am using tensorflow-models/speech-commands model to detect speech commands using ReactJs app, I'm able to initialize the recognizer in app and getting results also, but not sure how to identify the label based on the result of the model.

```
  componentDidMount () {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/ITEMS").then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(result => this.setState({
      products: result
    },() => {
       this.call()
    }));

  }

  async call() {

const recognizer = speechCommands.create('BROWSER_FFT')
await recognizer.ensureModelLoaded();
console.log("CALL",recognizer)
recognizer.listen(result => {
  // - result.scores contains the probability scores that correspond to
  //   recognizer.wordLabels().
  // - result.spectrogram contains the spectrogram of the recognized word.
  console.log("Result",result)
}, {
  includeSpectrogram: true,
  probabilityThreshold: 0.75
});

// Stop the recognition in 10 seconds.
setTimeout(() =>{
  console.log("Stopped listening")
  recognizer.stopListening()}, 10000);
  }
```

as you can see I'm initializing the recognizer on did mount and getting below results on speech commands from me, but not sure how to exactly identify the label model detected from result.

[image]

[image]

I believe I should refer scores property, but which one exactly is the predicted, not sure. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.scores` contains the probability that the given speech is a certain word.

> Which one exactly is the predicted

It depends of what is intended. Is the word with the highest priority or the topk considered to be the predicted values ?

Whatever the case, the indexes needed to be retrieved in `.score` and be used to retrieve corresponding words in `.words`

**retrieve the word with highest probability**:

```
recognizer.wordsLabels()[result.scores.indexOf(Math.max(...result.scores))];
```

**retrieve the topk words**

```
result.score.sort((a, b) => b-a).slice(0,k).map(s => result.scores.indexOf(s)).map(i => recognizer.wordsLabels()[i])
```

Comment: recognizer.wordLabels()[result.scores.indexOf(Math.max(...result.scores))] worked for me

Comment: `recognizer.wordsLabels()` returns `recognizer.words`